# Access Z coordinate in a LINESTRING Z in geopandas?

Tags: geopandas, shapely

I have a GeoDataFrame with a LINESTRING Z geometry where Z is my altitude for the lat/long. (There are other columns in the dataframe that I deleted for ease of sharing but are relevant when displaying the resulting track)

```
    TimeUTC Latitude    Longitude   AGL geometry
    0   2021-06-16 00:34:04+00:00   42.835413   -70.919610  82.2    LINESTRING Z (-70.91961 42.83541 82.20000, -70...
```

I would like to find the maximum Z value in that linestring but I am unable to find a way to access it or extract the x,y,z values in a way that I can determine the maximum value outside of the linestring.

`line.geometry.bounds` only returns the x,y min/max.

The best solution I could come up with was to turn all the points into a list of tuples:

`points = line.apply(lambda x: [y for y in x['geometry'].coords], axis=1)`

And then find the maximum value of the third element:

```
from operator import itemgetter
max(ft2,key=itemgetter(2))[2]
```

I hope there is a better solution available.

Thank you.

Comment: can you hard code an example GeoSeries of line strings and your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take your `lambda` function approach and just take it one step further:

```py
import numpy as np
line['geometry'].apply(lambda geom: np.max([coord[2] for coord in geom.coords]))
```

Here's a fully reproducible example from start to finish:

```py
import shapely
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd

linestring = shapely.geometry.LineString([[0,0,0],
                                          [1,1,1],
                                          [2,2,2]])

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],
                        'geometry':[linestring,
                                    linestring,
                                    linestring]})

gdf['max_z'] = (gdf['geometry']
                .apply(lambda geom: 
                       np.max([coord[2] for coord in geom.coords])))
```

In the example above, I create a new column called "`max_z`" that stores the maximum Z value for each row.

## Important note

This solution will only work if you **exclusively** have `LineString`s in your geometries. If, for example, you have `MultiLineString`s, you'll have to adapt the function I wrote to take care of that.

Comment: I have a follow on question that I feel falls into a paid consulting category rather than a question of public interest, partly due to the breadth of the question and partly due to potential IP.  If you are interested, my Twitter handle is in my profile.

If the right thing to do is ask the meta question here, I am happy to do so. I may have to present the problem as semi-pseudo code.

Comment: Sounds good! Feel free to reach me via email. I'm posting my email address in the comment below and immediately deleting it from Stack Overflow, mostly because I don't want to leave my email out in public. You'll be able to retrieve my deleted message from the email address you have associated with your Stack Overflow account. If you need me to re-send my address, just let me know.